# calibrating Camera around a centered Circle (Maths)

Tags: math, three.js, camera

im trying to move a camera in three js centered with the movements of the mouse. everything is working fine and im using

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    mousePosition.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mousePosition.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}
```

to get the position from -1 to 1. What i want to add now is that the camera can't get into a circle with the position 0/0 (the middle of the browser screen). Its hard to explain but i want to move the camera on the line, radius of this circle around until the x or y value gets out of a range from -0.5 to 0.5. This is how the camera is updated:

```
camOffset.x += (mousePosition.x - camOffset.x) * 0.1;
camOffset.y += (mousePosition.y - camOffset.y) * 0.1;
camera.position.x += camOffset.x * 30;
camera.position.y += camOffset.y * 30;
```

hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: So if the mouse position has magnitude less than 0.5, you want the camera position to have the same direction as the mouse position, but with magnitude 0.5, is that right?

Comment: yeah you understood what i meant! i have to add, the camera is moved on a spline which of course hits exactly the center of the camera which occurs an weird looking effect. thats why im trying to get some space around it with the circle.

Comment: @Beta do you know a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the syntax of javascript (or whatever this code is), but something like this should work:

```
mag2 = camera.position.x * camera.position.x + camera.position.y * camera.position.y;
if(mag2 < 0.01) // to prevent divide-by-zero if the camera hits the origin
  camera.position.x = 0.5;
else
 if(mag2 < 0.25)
   {
     k = 0.5/sqrt(mag2);
     camera.position.x *= k;
     camera.position.y *= k;
   }
```

Comment: thank you so much! thats not the code i needed but i solved it with that help! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use THREE.Spherical() for efficient conversion of x,y,z to phi, theta. It will reduce your effort and give you a better understanding of camera movement. Change only theta of camera to rotate it in a circle.

```
    var delta = mousePosition.x - camOffset.x;
    var rotMult = delta * rollSpeed;// adjust this according to your need.
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    var center = new THREE.Vector3();
    var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
    vector.copy( camera.position ).sub( center );
    spherical.setFromVector3( vector );
    spherical.theta += this.rotationVector.y * rotMult;
    spherical.makeSafe();
    vector.setFromSpherical( spherical );
    camera.position.copy( center ).add( vector );
    camera.lookAt( center );
```

Comment: in addition i'm moving the camera on a spline, it automatically looks a bit forward in 3d space. i'm trying to adjust your code to make it work for me! i have to use the orbit controls right?

Comment: oh im sorry amritesh i think you did not unterstand what an effect i wanted to create. take a quick look at lukasgoj.com/amusd, drop in an mp3 and you can follow the spline. now i want the camera movement to move around the radius of an 2d circle which is centered in the position of the screen so the spline does not hit the center of the view field

Comment: In that case you can use x,y to r,theta conversion. Here is a fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/cap34u52/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
    var mag2 = mousePosition.x * mousePosition.x + mousePosition.y * mousePosition.y;
    var radius = 0.3;
    if(mag2 < radius){
        if(mousePosition.x <=0 && mousePosition.y >=0){ //1 quadrant
            camOffset.x += ((mousePosition.x - camOffset.x)-radius) * 0.1;
            camOffset.y += ((mousePosition.y - camOffset.y)+radius) * 0.1;               
        }else if(mousePosition.x >0 && mousePosition.y >=0){ //2 quadrant
            camOffset.x += ((mousePosition.x - camOffset.x)+radius) * 0.1;
            camOffset.y += ((mousePosition.y - camOffset.y)+radius) * 0.1;                  
        }else if(mousePosition.x <=0 && mousePosition.y <0){
            camOffset.x += ((mousePosition.x - camOffset.x)-radius) * 0.1;
            camOffset.y += ((mousePosition.y - camOffset.y)-radius) * 0.1;                
        }else if(mousePosition.x >0 && mousePosition.y <0){
            camOffset.x += ((mousePosition.x - camOffset.x)+radius) * 0.1;
            camOffset.y += ((mousePosition.y - camOffset.y)-radius) * 0.1;               
        }       
        camera.position.x += camOffset.x * 30;
        camera.position.y += camOffset.y * 30;
    }else{
        camOffset.x += (mousePosition.x - camOffset.x) * 0.1;
        camOffset.y += (mousePosition.y - camOffset.y) * 0.1;
        camera.position.x += camOffset.x * 30;
        camera.position.y += camOffset.y * 30;
    }
```